# Locale independent string search in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, locale

Is there a way for searching / comparing strings without consideration of locale?

I mean: if I have two input sources on my keyboard (Russian and English) and I start typing - I want to search word without consideration what input source is active at the moment.

And I'll find string contained "Search" without metter what I've typed "search" or "ыуфкср"

Thanks.

Comment: You want to know the physical keys used rather than what they may be mapped to? Sort of the way [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/ыуфкср) suggests that I meant "search" when I give it "ыуфкср"?

Comment: yep, exactly, how google translate provides variants? I want to do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply need to do search by two phrases: the original input and the result of conversion to another keyboard layout.  You would have a conversion map like this:

```
{
    a: 'ф',
    s: 'ы',
    d: 'в',
    f: 'а',
    ...
}
```

Comment: It was first what I've thinking about. But it's awful decision, I will do like that if I will not found correct way... Intresting, how google translator and VK.com do it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this approach. You have a pretty specific scenario that involves specific locales and specific keyboard layouts (as was noted, there are many different keyboard layouts, not just qwerty). I don't think there are ready mechanisms in native browser JavaScript that let you do this, it's not even transliteration. I'm on my phone right now so can't check VK implementation...

Comment: VK code is a lot of mess :) it's hard to find how do they do smth :) And I think that they do hash map :) Intresting how it's work for Chinese or others (not Russian)

Answer (score 1):

When I think about it, I come to the conclusion that there is no correct way to implement this, even if we want such opportunity. One reason: there may be different keyboards (when on one keyboard 'a' is equal to 'ф' and on other one it is equal to 'ы'). So probably you should implement such functionllity by your self.

Comment: but I know keycode and it's same for 's' and 'ы'. Are there no way to do only for Russian and English? Like Vkontakte do. I'm looking for the way for doing that without hash table of variants...

Comment: To my knowledge there is no pre-existing mapping between keycodes and charcodes

Comment: Yep, and it's awful. By the way, I know char code, cuz I'm working with user input...

Comment: But since there are many different keyboard layouts there is no single umbrella solution to the task.